# Destructuring array and accessing the first element

Tags: ecmascript-6

I made and API call using fetch to get JSON data. That data is then passed to my function `displayCartTotal`, which accepts a parameter that uses de-structuring to obtain results.

In `displayCartTotal`, I want to de-structure the first item into the `results` array, into a data variable. Next, use object de-structuring to obtain the `itemsInCart` and `buyerCountry` properties of the data.

I have tried de-structuring the array, but is not working, also when i do `typeof()` on the data I receive, I get "object".

Here is format of the JSON data

```
{
    results: [{
        itemsInCart: [{
            name: "Jolof Rice",
            price: 80,
            qty: 2
        }, {
            name: "Jolof Rice",
            price: 80,
            qty: 2
        }],
        buyerCountry: "Uganda"
    }],
    info: {
        seed: "85e0e8ca0e095f74",
        results: "1",
        page: "1",
        version: "0.1",
        time: {
            instruct: 11,
            generate: 5
        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
const displayCartTotal = ({results}) => {           
    const [data] = results;
    const [itemsInCart,buyerCountry] = data;
    return results;
};

const fetchBill = () => {
    const api = 'https://randomapi.com/api/006b08a801d82d0c9824dcfdfdfa3b3c';
    fetch(api)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => displayCartTotal(data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
};
```

I expect to de-structure the first item in the `results` array into a data variable. And also to use object de-structuring to obtain the `itemsInCart` and `buyerCountry` properties of data.

Comment: Data is an object, not an array.

Comment: so how do achieve my aim. I need help, can you help me with a sample to do that?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: NB: `displayCartTotal` is not displaying anything; it just returns the whole `results`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried placing the nth position of the object

```
const displayCartTotal= ({results})=>{
    const {0: data} = results;
    const {itemsInCart, buyerCountry} = data;
  }
```